# I need to identify strings, in sql server, that contain the same keywords as a given string in no particular order

Tags: sql-server, string, matching

I checked similar questions, but I don't want to use Full Text Search and I didn't find anything else that appeared to match my needs, so I wrote this code below that returns a nominal percentage word match for a pair of strings.

It works by removing "noise" words and punctuation, then putting all the remaining words into a table variable (one for each of the two strings) then joining the two tables and counting the joins. The join count is then divided by the word count from one of the strings to give a (nominal) percentage. It works OK, but it's a bit slow when I use it in a select to identify the 5 best matches from a few thousand strings!

So I either need a better approach or any good ideas to improve speed...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [GLOBAL].[COMPARETITLESFUNC] 
(

@title1 nvarchar(4000), @title2 nvarchar(4000)-- , @pcmatch int output
)
returns int
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @pcm int, @matchedrows int, @totalwordcount int, @Counter int, @mul int;
DECLARE @words1 table (word nvarchar(500));
DECLARE @words2 table (word nvarchar(500));
DECLARE @S nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @temp nvarchar(4000);


set @pcm = 0;
set @matchedrows = 0;
set @totalwordcount = 0;
set @S = ' ';   -- split char may be replace with other strings
set @temp = '';
set @mul = 1;

-- build two temp tables of the words from each string excluding common/noise words
-- words to exclude: in on the and verizon can too if it a at of or for by your with & 
-- maybe one day store exclusion words in a codelist called compexclude if maintenance of them becomes an issue
-- join the tables and count the rows returned and divide by the total number of words in the two strings 

--## first convert all strings to lower case and remove any extraneous spaces and any other punctuation
set @title1 = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@title1,':',@S),';',@S),',',@S),'!',@S),'-',@S),'?',@S),'.',@S),'%',@S),'$',@S),'&',@S),'£',@S),'"',@S) -- remove unwanted punctuation
set @title2 = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@title2,':',@S),';',@S),',',@S),'!',@S),'-',@S),'?',@S),'.',@S),'%',@S),'$',@S),'&',@S),'£',@S),'"',@S) -- remove unwanted punctuation
set @title1 = replace(replace(replace(@title1,@S+@S,@S),@S+@S,@S),@S+@S,@S); -- replace any multiple seps created
set @title2 = replace(replace(replace(@title2,@S+@S,@S),@S+@S,@S),@S+@S,@S); -- replace any multiple seps created
set @title1 = ltrim(rtrim(lower(@title1))) + @S; -- split char(s) on end ensures we get last item
set @title2 = ltrim(rtrim(lower(@title2))) + @S; -- split char(s) on end ensures we get last item

--## then split both strings into their tables  
set @Counter = 1; 
WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@S, @title1) > 0 ) 
BEGIN  
    INSERT  INTO @words1 (word) SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@title1, 1, CHARINDEX(@S, @title1) - 1)));

    SET @title1 = SUBSTRING(@title1, CHARINDEX(@S, @title1) + 1, LEN(@title1));

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; 
END;

set @Counter = 1; 
WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@S, @title2) > 0 ) 
BEGIN  
    INSERT  INTO @words2 (word) SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@title2, 1, CHARINDEX(@S, @title2) - 1)));

    SET @title2 = SUBSTRING(@title2, CHARINDEX(@S, @title2) + 1, LEN(@title2));

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; 
END;


--## delete non reqd words
delete from @words1 where word in ('&', 'a', 'and', 'at', 'by', 'can', 'for', 'if', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'too', 'verizon', 'with', 'your');
delete from @words2 where word in ('&', 'a', 'and', 'at', 'by', 'can', 'for', 'if', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'too', 'verizon', 'with', 'your');

--## union tables and count reqd words OR just count words in title1 and don't double final percentage to gain a better match
--select  @totalwordcount = count(*) from  (select * from @words1 union all select * from @words2) x ;
-- set @mul = 2;
select  @totalwordcount = count(*) from  @words1;
--print 'totalwordcount:' + cast(@totalwordcount as varchar(10));

select @temp = @temp + '|' + word from  (select * from @words1 union all select * from @words2) x ;
--print @temp;

--## join tables and count result and count words in the two tables
select  @pcm = count(*) from  @words1 w1 JOIN @words2 w2 on w1.word = w2.word;
--print 'joins:' + cast(@pcm as varchar(10));


--## calculate the pc and return
set @pcm = ((@pcm * 100)/@totalwordcount) * @mul;

--print 'pc is:' + cast(@pcm as varchar(10));
-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @pcm;

END
```

Anyway, even if no one can come up with any improvements, I guess at least this code will be available for anyone else with a similar need whose doesn't wish to use FTS or any third-party library.

Comment: Have you tried to do this with views? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: FTS would be far superior to this RBAR approach. This is going to horribly slow.

Comment: @Gonzalo: not sure how a view would help me per se.  I use my function in a select to pull the best matches from my few thousand rows; perhaps that's what you meant?

Comment: @Sean Lange: Yes, but I have multiple databases to deal with and if the opportunity arises for me to make the required FTS changes, then I'll move to that approach. The 3 seconds it takes **is** slow, but thankfully scrapes in as **just** acceptable for filling in a sidebar with similar documents on a web page .

Comment: @JohnEllis I was thinking about create a view with that the info of the table you want joined and the text with the "noise" words stripped. When you want to search you could select in that view.

Comment: @JohnEllis, did my answer help you?

Comment: @shnugo - sorry, unfortunately I have been unable to try this as I am already over my project deadline, but I will try it as soon as I have even a few minutes. I'll mark it as the accepted answer because it DOES answer my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is very much "row based". Here is a set based approach, less code, better maintenance and faster...

```
DECLARE @forbiddenWords TABLE(item VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @forbiddenWords VALUES ('&'),( 'a'),( 'and'),( 'at'),( 'by'),( 'can'),( 'for'),( 'if'),( 'in'),( 'is'),( 'it'),( 'of'),( 'on'),( 'or'),( 'the'),( 'this'),( 'to'),( 'too'),( 'verizon'),( 'with'),( 'your')

DECLARE @breakingCharacters TABLE(item VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @breakingCharacters VALUES(':'),(';'),(','),('!'),('-'),('?'),('.'),('%'),('$'),('&'),('£'),('"');

DECLARE @Phrase1 VARCHAR(MAX)='This is a text where I try to find similar words. Let''s see if it works!';
DECLARE @Phrase2 VARCHAR(MAX)='This is another text where I use some words of Phrase1 to check their similarity!';

--Replace all breaking Characters
SELECT @Phrase1=REPLACE(@Phrase1,item,' ')
FROM @breakingCharacters;

SELECT @Phrase2=REPLACE(@Phrase2,item,' ')
FROM @breakingCharacters;


WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(LOWER(@Phrase1),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS xml) AS Phrase1AsXml
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(LOWER(@Phrase2),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS xml) AS Phrase2AsXml
)
,Phrase1AsFilteredWords AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT The.word.value('.','varchar(max)') AS OneWord
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY Phrase1AsXml.nodes('/x') AS The(word)
    WHERE LEN(The.word.value('.','varchar(max)'))>0
          AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @forbiddenWords AS fw WHERE fw.item = The.word.value('.','varchar(max)') )
)
,Phrase2AsFilteredWords AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT The.word.value('.','varchar(max)') AS OneWord
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY Phrase2AsXml.nodes('/x') AS The(word)
    WHERE LEN(The.word.value('.','varchar(max)'))>0
          AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @forbiddenWords AS fw WHERE fw.item = The.word.value('.','varchar(max)') )
)
,CommonWords AS
(
    SELECT p1.OneWord
    FROM Phrase1AsFilteredWords AS p1
    INNER JOIN Phrase2AsFilteredWords AS p2 ON p1.OneWord=p2.OneWord
)
,WordCounter AS
(
    SELECT
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Phrase1AsFilteredWords) AS CountPhrase1
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Phrase2AsFilteredWords) AS CountPhrase2
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CommonWords) AS CountCommon
)
SELECT WordCounter.*
      ,(CountCommon*100) / CountPhrase1 AS Phrase1PC
      ,(CountCommon*100) / CountPhrase2 AS Phrase2PC
      ,STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + OneWord
        FROM CommonWords 
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,2,'') AS CommonWords
FROM WordCounter
```

The result :

```
CountPhrase1    CountPhrase2    CountCommon Phrase1PC   Phrase2PC   CommonWords
10              11              4           40          36          i, text, where, words
```

One hint: If you compare many with many it will cost a lot to do the calculation again and again. I'd advise you to prepare all phrases in one go and compare these prepared results...

One more hint: If you do this more often and your phrases don't change, it could be clever to store the preparated word list permanently.

Happy coding!

Comment: Wow, a completely different approach, thank you! I'll try yours out and see what kind of speed improvements I can get.